# DotNet patches relevant to OS or applications

Tags: windows, .net-framework, wsus

I have doubts regarding DotNet patches, which are released over MS Security Bulletins, #patchtuesaday. Do we have to update all DotNet patches which are released over #patchthuesday? Are they really related to Microsoft Server Operating System (W2k3, W3K8 - R2 & W12K) or does it depend upon the application installed on the servers, which requires DotNet as a prerequisite?

If DotNet patches are application relevant, could you please justify how DotNet patches are not relevant for operating systems, so that I can put it in front of my colleagues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET patches apply *only* to the .NET Framework.  If the Frameworks are installed, they should be patched.

I do not believe any Windows Server OS *requires* the .NET Framework for functionality, as they are optional components.  However, that only applies to the base OS.  There may be optional components which are not installed by default that require them.

Obviously, there are MS servers, like SQL server, that require the Frameworks to function.

In the end, if MS Update is showing the need for a .NET patch, there is no reason not to apply it.